# Can I get the user longitude and latitude from their address in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, latitude-longitude

As the title says, I am trying to derive the user's location from their address as they input in into the app however I have not found any way to do this. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function that you can use to get location from address

```
func getLocation(from address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?)-> Void) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard let placemarks = placemarks,
        let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(location)
    }
}
```

So let's say if i have this address:

```
let address = "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014"
```

**Usage**

```
getLocation(from: address) { location in
    print("Location is", location.debugDescription)
    // Location is Optional(__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.799372, longitude: -89.644458))

   print(location.latitude) // result 39.799372
   print(location.longitude) // result -89.644458


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Just one question. When I use the function as you have described above, it is always run after all the code in my switch statement. Where should I call the function so this does not happen? Thank you.

Comment: how you are using it ? its async function

Answer (score 2):

We can get the `coordinate` from the below code,

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCoordinatesFromPlace(place: "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014")
    }

    func getCoordinatesFromPlace(place: String){

        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(place) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard
                let placemarks = placemarks,
                let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate
            else {
                // handle no location found
                return
            }
            print(location.latitude)
            print(location.longitude)

        }
    }

}
```